# How to create a word doc with html android

Tags: android

Is this possible to create a word doc using the html in andriod, can i get any samples for creating word doc using html in android.

or any other library can use to create a word doc

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this: http://code.google.com/p/java2word

Is Simple:

```
Document myDoc = new Document();
myDoc.getBody().addEle(new Heading("Heading"));
myDoc.getBody().addEle(new Paragraph("paragraph 1")
```

Comment: hi thanks @josedlujam the lib you mention working fine for me but i have to attach a image to doc when i try to attach image using [Image.from_WEB_URL("http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png")] app getting crash with class not found error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   javax.imageio.ImageIO can you help me how to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

Please install Office Suite Apps in your Android Mobile/Tablet. I am using it for last 6 months and it is performing well.